# Codeigniter display product expiration date instead of stock

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to instead of the stock alert products, Display expiration date alert products.

```
<?php

                foreach ($stock as $item) {
                    echo '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge badge-danger float-xs-right">' . +$item['qty'] . ' ' . $item['unit'] . '</span> <a href="' . base_url() . 'products/edit?id=' . $item['pid'] . '">' . $item['product_name'] . '  </a><small class="purple"> <i class="ft-map-pin"></i> ' . $item['title'] . '</small>
                            </li>';
                } ?>
```

and

```
    public function stock()
{
    $whr = '';
            if ($this->aauth->get_user()->loc) {
     $whr = ' AND (lmpos_warehouse.loc=' . $this->aauth->get_user()->loc . ')';
    } elseif (!BDATA) {
     $whr = ' AND (lmpos_warehouse.loc=0)';
    }

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT lmpos_products.*,lmpos_warehouse.title FROM lmpos_products LEFT JOIN lmpos_warehouse ON lmpos_products.warehouse=lmpos_warehouse.id  WHERE (lmpos_products.qty<=lmpos_products.alert) $whr ORDER BY lmpos_products.product_name ASC LIMIT 10");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

note: In the table of products on the database, there is an expiration date for each product

[You can see the current result in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OwKg.png)

Comment: what is your expiration date column name on the database?

Comment: expiration date column name is expiry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have an database table column for the expiration date named `exp`, just change the badge codes from `+$item['qty'] . ' ' . $item['unit']` to `date("F jS, Y", strtotime($item['exp'])` :

```php
    foreach ($stock as $item) {
        echo '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge badge-danger float-xs-right">' . date("F jS, Y", strtotime($item['exp']) . '</span> <a href="' . base_url() . 'products/edit?id=' . $item['pid'] . '">' . $item['product_name'] . '  </a><small class="purple"> <i class="ft-map-pin"></i> ' . $item['title'] . '</small>
                </li>';
    }
```

This will display the expiration date in human readable format

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved. There was only one syntax error that was a little parentheses

Comment: `foreach ($stock as $item) {
     echo '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge badge-danger float-xs-right">' . date("d-m-Y", strtotime($item['exp'])) . '</span> <a href="' . base_url() . 'products/edit?id=' . $item['pid'] . '">' . $item['product_name'] . '  </a><small class="purple"> <i class="ft-map-pin"></i> ' . $item['title'] . '</small>
             </li>';
 }`

thanks again